# How to fire a click event in a ul, li or div in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to fire off a click event in a reactjs component but it is not working. I have tried this unsuccessfully in a `div`, `ul`, `li` and even a button. I have a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k9m3wr85o3)

*I have had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703016/onclick-event-not-firing-in-reactjs), but the issue is not the one I am facing, as can be seen in the demo above*

Comment: onClick expect a function, use this: `onClick={() => console.log("Hi")}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onClick` accepts to be a function and would be written as

```
<button onClick={() => {console.log("Hi")}}>Hello</button>
```

or

```
handleClick() {
    console.log('Hi');
}
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Hello</button>
```

instead of

```
<button onClick={console.log("Hi")}>Hello</button>
```

If you write `onClick={console.log("Hi")}` , on each `render` the value for `onClick` is evaluated and hence `Hi` is seen on `console`

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a function in the event handler, not call the function. See:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {console.log("Hi")}}>Hello</button>
    </div>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```